# problem with animationImages array

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, animation, uiimageview

here is my code :

```
-(void) createNewImage {

image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"oeufgrisé.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"boutonplay_03.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"boutonpause_03.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_05.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"mangeurcentremieu3_03.png"],nil];
[image setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
image.animationDuration =1.5;
[image startAnimating];      

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

}
```

This code doesn't work, I don't know why. I have always this warning on line "imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];" :Incompatible ObjectiveC type struct UIImageView*' expected struct UIImage*' when passing argument 1 of initWithImage from distinct Objective C type

Answer (score 2):

You can set animation images to UIImageView , and not to UIImage.

```
-(void) createNewImage {
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];

    imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"oeufgrisé.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"boutonplay_03.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"boutonpause_03.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_05.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"mangeurcentremieu3_03.png"],nil];
    [imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
    imageView.animationDuration =1.5;
    [imageView startAnimating]; 
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(setLastImage:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

 }

-(void)setLastImage:(id)obj
{
    [imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mangeurcentremieu3_03.png"] waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: yes but what I want is that after that the animation is finished, imageView is "mangeurcentremieu3_03.png.

Comment: You can do as what I have mentioned. After 15 seconds, (10 times of 1.5 sec animation), the animation will be over and the imageview will have "mangeurcentremieu3_03.png" image.

Comment: I have edited my answer so that the imageview will have the image after 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing:

```
image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
```

then `image` is an `UIImageView` (review the code where you allocate it). That is the reason why you get the error, since `initWithImage` expects an object of type UIImage:

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
```

Either you did not mean `image` to be an image view, or possibly you don't need to allocate a second UIImageView in your method and can just use `image`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `image` is a UIImageView and not a UIImage. You can only create animationImages for UIImageViews.